# jQuery Colorbox close event only trigger once

Tags: jquery, colorbox

i will explain my problem in steps, to make my problem clear.

i have two pages.

page #1 is for showing a result page with a table, with informations about accounts
page #2 is a detailview for the accounts and opens up in a colorbox.

on other colorbox pages i used inline divs and created a button with a javascript call $('cboxClose').click(); to close the colorbox when the user is clicking on this button.

but now i have a seperate page with a link which gets called by the colorbox.
now, when i open the colorbox, everything works fine, the informations are shown and also the button is working. but only one time.
when i open the page, i can click the X on the top right corner, and i can also use the close button i placed in the page with the $('cboxClose').click(); event. but when i openup another color box, by clicking the same link or another one, the popup appears, and the button on the bottom is not reacting anymore. just the X in the top right corner is working.

this also happens if i click the X on the first open. the close button with the event just works on the first open up and then it stops working.
can someone explain me what i am doing wrong?

the button is like this

```
<div id="closeButton" class="buttonImage" onclick="$('#cboxClose').click();">Close Button</div>
```

i hope someone can help me :-( i dont understand why he only fires on the first time.

greetings
Marco

Comment: do you get any error messages?

Comment: no, i get nothing. when i place the click call into a javascript method with a alert("hoho"); i get the hoho, but the .click() is not triggered.

Comment: ok but do you get the alert once or everytime you click?

Comment: yes, i do. so it seems that the xbocClose is not reachable after the first time. and i dont understand why :-/

Comment: you could try to do the following: instead of 'hoho' alert($('#cboxClose').length) (or console.log()) if you know how to)